# duplicate "deleted_at" on sql update request with Laravel 5.5

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.5

i created a destroy method in a controller :

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $sector = Sector::findOrFail($id);
    // on update lang_sector pour chaque id
    $sector_ids = $sector->langs()->allRelatedIds();
    foreach ($sector_ids as $id){
        $sector->langs()->updateExistingPivot($id, ['lang_sector.deleted_at' => Carbon::now(), 'lang_sector.updated_at' => Carbon::now()]);
    }
    $sector->valuechains()->update(
        [
            'valuechains.deleted_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'valuechains.updated_at' => Carbon::now()
        ]
    );

    Sector::where('id', $id)->delete();
}
```

In my model :

```
protected $table = "sectors";
protected $fillable = ['admin_id'];
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at'
];
public function langs() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lang')
        ->withPivot(
            'sectname',
            'sectshortname',
            'sectdescription',
            'sectshortdescription'
        )
        ->withTimestamps();
}

public function valuechains()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Valuechain');
}
public function segments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Segment', 'App\Valuechain');
}
public function keyneeds()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Keyneed', 'App\Segment', 'App\Valuechain');
}
```

When i destroy my entry i have an issue with the sql request :

update `valuechains` set `valuechains`.`deleted_at` = '2018-05-09 16:10:32', `valuechains`.`updated_at` = '2018-05-09 16:10:32', `updated_at` = '2018-05-09 16:10:32' where `valuechains`.`sector_id` = '2' and `valuechains`.`sector_id` is not null

An updated_at is appearing without any particular reason ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are explicitly asking for the `updated_at` column to be set in this line:

```
'valuechains.updated_at' => Carbon::now()
```

Laravel is automatically setting `updated_at` during the UPDATE, so you dont need to explicitly update it yourself.

You should be able to remove that explicit line and `updated_at` will still be updated.

Laravel **should** be smart enough to detect the duplicate column update, alas its not.

Comment: So obvious ... thanks for your help ! it works fine ... i meet similar issues with segments and keyneeds ... i didn't find how to update also the pivot tables like lang_valuechain, lang_segment and lang_keyneed ... In fact i'm trying to do a cascade update on several tables and pivot tables ...